# Is our reality real?

Tags: reality, subjectivity

Our perception of reality is flawed. Not only are we limited to a narrow bandwidth of light and sound waves, but size and shape depend on our angle and distance from an object. The reality we percieve is a creation of the mind, based on stimuli from our sense organs and is a mere snapshot of reality from one particular location at one particular moment in time. Sounds and colors do not even exist objectively. So how can we call our reality is real?

Comment: @Virmaoir : There might be many possible explicit answers to this question, but it is possible to provide an objective answer that points the OP in the direction of philosophers and topics that could help him do further research, and fit the philosophy SE guidelines.

Comment: Can you define "real" or give an example of something that counts as real, so you can provide a benchmark to make a useful distinction from? The poverty of scepticism...

Comment: Is pain real? Does evil exist? What about a shadow? Can the absence of something be said to exist?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question whose answers likely number in the thousands.  In fact, [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology) is a major branch of philosophy dedicated entirely to answering your question.  Ontology can be contrasted with [epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology), which concerns what we can know.  The boundary between the two is *full* of contrasting theories which try to link the two, as you do with your question "So how can we call our reality real?"

Perhaps of specific interest to you would be the exploration of [physicalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physicalism), [dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism_%28philosophy_of_mind%29), and [idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealism), along with the myriad of pluralist [approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralism_%28philosophy%29).

- Physicalism claims everything supervenes on physical matter (meaning everything in "reality" is actually made of matter)
- Dualism claims there are both physical matter and a "mind" substance which is not made of matter.
- Idealism claims there is only a mental substance, and no physical matter
- Pulralism explores cases where reality might be made of more than two substances.

As it turns out, differentiating between these approaches is impossible with [empiricism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism), one sub-branch of epistemology.

Finally, consider that your question "So how can we call our reality real?" has the word "call" in it.  You are actually asking a linguistic question about how we use the words "reality" and "real."  The trivial answer is actually "because reality is defined to be that which is real."  Lingustically, we use words to describe things when we need to describe things.  Thus, the answer to your question may be "because we can."

Hopefully the links provided here will help you expand your understanding of philosophy to better craft specific questions related to "how can we call our reality real," which is one of the larger philosophical questions of all time, and is likely not to have a singular answer any time soon.